# Removing Duplicates from one Column based on conditions of another in R

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements

I have a dataset that I'm attempting to count the number of retained customers by order period, but in the dataset there were many duplicates due to orders being ordered by the same customer over several periods of time so they were included as a new entry (observation) in the dataset. Unfortunately , many of these contain repeated IDs/Person numbers so I was wondering if there was any type of regex or filter I could possibly use that would check the **retained** column then remove the duplicated ID/Person number if the value in ****retained****  is the same.

```
tibble::tribble(
                    ~PERSONUM,      ~ID, ~ORDER_PERIOD, ~retained,
                  10001685, 10109887,         "201750",       "Y",
                  10001685, 10109887,         "201850",       "Y",
                  10001685, 10109887,         "201950",       "Y",
                  10005733, 10162571,         "201550",       "Y",
                  10005787, 10112896,         "201550",       "Y",
                  10005795, 10112901,         "201550",       "Y",
                  10005795, 10112901,         "201650",       "Y",
                  10005795, 10112901,         "201750",       "Y",
                  10020043, 10156305,         "202050",       "Y",
                  10020165, 10122910,         "201750",       "Y",
                  10020165, 10122910,         "201850",       "Y",
                  10020649, 10123585,         "201550",       "N",
                  10028842, 10128545,         "201750",       "Y",
                  52300090, 10147580,         "201850",       "N",
                  52300740, 10149860,         "201650",       "N",
                  52300749, 10135925,         "201750",       "Y",
                  52300749, 10135925,         "201850",       "Y",
                  52300917, 10140173,         "201650",       "Y",
                  52300917, 10140173,         "201750",       "Y",
                  52300917, 10140173,         "201850",       "Y"
                  )
```

I was considering using df %>% filter(ID==ID) but obviously the ID will always equal itself, I know there are duplicate functions and I've thought about using something like

```
df_cleaned <-df[!duplicated(df),]
```

but I need the code to apply some sort of condition that looks at the retained column first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **distinct** function from **dplyr**

```
df_cleaned <- df %>% distinct(PERSONUM, retained,.keep_all=TRUE)
```

The above code keeps records who have distinct "PERSONUM" and "retained" values

Comment: is that what the .keep_all argument specifies? Thank you, on first glance it seems to work! Now, do you know if this will work for more than one column? If say, I had a retained variable and possibly another column that states whether the customer is new or returning?

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz yes it also works for more than "one" column. You just need to add it inside inside the function like "distinct(PERSONUM, retained,<new_column>, .keep_all=TRUE)"

Comment: The .keep_all argument specifies that other columns not specified inside the function (like ID or ORDER_PERIOD) will be kept (not dropped)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following code does what the question asks for.
It groups by `ID` and `retained` and then keeps only the first row of each group, eliminating the duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)

orders %>%
  group_by(ID, retained) %>%
  filter(row_number() == first(row_number()))
```

---

### Note

[DDT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68136751/8245406) is simpler and the results of that code and of the code above are `identical` after `ungroup`ing the above:

```
orders %>%
  group_by(ID, retained) %>%
  filter(row_number() == first(row_number())) %>%
  ungroup() -> df1

orders %>% distinct(ID, retained, .keep_all = TRUE) -> df2

identical(df1, df2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: now, just curious, why are you ungrouping at the end of the pipe? Also, is this robust enough for multiple rows that may have different data in columns but the same ID?

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz To have `identical` work. Without it the result will have an attribute `attr(*, "groups")`.

Comment: thank you! I upvoted you as well, because I liked your second solution. Although, I gave the "answer" to @DDT

Comment: @BenjaminDiaz Yes, that is the point of the final Note. A simpler and identical answer is better. Thanks for the upvote.